# python reading file into datastructure

Tags: python, file, text

I have a TXT file like https://pastebin.com/SVjVTPTA.

How can I read the x and y values into some kind of data structure eg a 2d array or dictionary?

I tried this but it does not work:

```
f= open('text.txt', 'r')
newDict = {}
for line in f:
    n, r, t = line.strip().split(' ')
    newDict[k.strip()] = v.strip()
```

If you have a better and more concise solution then my attempt, please post here for this poor buddy. Please have mercy on me, I am a beginner in python and using computers!

Comment: what is k and v here ?

Comment: im really not sure, just a beginner... i thought it was the key and value of the split?

Comment: I cannot access your online storage. Could you please post the first 3 lines of the txt-file? Depending on what data (structure) is in the file and on what you want to do with the data, there are libraries for python which have good importer functions for reading data in, which can be easily tweaked to any kind of the normally used structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this if you want the o/p in dict format. Also orderdDict will keep your order of your data:

```
with open('j.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    newDct = {i.strip().split()[0]:i.strip().split()[1] for i in lines[2:]}
print(newdict)
```

The o/p will be like :

```
{'0.25': '1.03516', '-0.25': '1.09766', '0.00': '1.00000', '1.50': '1.56250', '0.75': '1.03516', '1.00': '1.00000', '2.00': '5.00000', '-1.00': '5.00000', '-1.75': '24.16016', '1.25': '1.09766', '-1.25': '8.91016', '-0.50': '1.56250', '1.75': '2.72266', '-1.50': '15.06250', '2.25': '8.91016', '2.75': '24.16016', '2.50': '15.06250', '-0.75': '2.72266', '-2.00': '37.00000', '0.50': '1.06250'}
```

If you want it in 2d array here another way :

```
with open('j.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lst = [i.strip().split() for i in lines[2:]]
print(lst)
```

Comment: i dont want ordered

Answer (score 0):

If you use dictionary you may loss some values. As dictionary `key` should be unique.

To store the data in a `2D` array you can do:

1. Traverse all the lines
2. For each line splits the two numbers and put into a list (if possible)

You can achieve this by following script

`data_parse.py`:

```
result = []
with open("test.txt") as data_file:
    lines = data_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        try:
            result.append(list(map(float, line.strip().split())))
        except:
            pass
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[-2.0, 37.0], [-1.75, 24.16016], [-1.5, 15.0625], [-1.25, 8.91016], [-1.0, 5.0], [-0.75, 2.72266], [-0.5, 1.5625], [-0.25, 1.09766], [0.0, 1.0], [0.25, 1.03516], [0.5, 1.0625], [0.75, 1.03516], [1.0, 1.0], [1.25, 1.09766], [1.5, 1.5625], [1.75, 2.72266], [2.0, 5.0], [2.25, 8.91016], [2.5, 15.0625], [2.75, 24.16016]]
```